# Most efficient way of dividing rows by name and then transposing to one column for each name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using standard SQL in Google Bigquery. So I have some data about metrics in this format:

```
Date        | metric_name  | metric_level
01/02/2019  | metric_one   | 1
02/03/2019  | metric_one   | 2
14/02/2019  | metric_two   | 6
17/02/2019  | metric_two   | 4
01/03/2019  | metric_three | 2
10/03/2019  | metric_three | 7
```

I want to get it in this format, date history going back one year, and then each metric filled in for each date. If a metric has no data for a particular date then it uses the most recent data point:

```
Date        | metric_one   | metric_two   | metric_three
..........
01/02/2019  | 1            | null         | null
02/02/2019  | 1            | null         | null
03/02/2019  | 1            | null         | null
...........
...........
13/02/2019  | 1            | null         | null
14/02/2019  | 1            | 6            | null
15/02/2019  | 1            | 6            | null
...........
...........
09/03/2019  | 2            | 4            | 2
10/03/2019  | 2            | 4            | 7
11/03/2019  | 2            | 4            | 7
...........
```

and so on.

I've managed to write some code that does this, but I want to know if there's a more efficient way of doing it. There are actually a lot more than 3 metrics, so if I can make it more efficient in any way then it will save a lot of resources in the long run.

This is my code

```
    WITH date_arr AS(

        SELECT 
        date

        FROM UNNEST(
            GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
                DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 365 DAY), 
                CURRENT_DATE(), 
                INTERVAL 1 day
            )
        ) AS date

    ),

    metric_one_raw AS (

        SELECT 
        date,
        metric_level

        FROM database
        WHERE metric_name = 'metric_one'

    ),

    metric_one_gapless AS (

        SELECT
        d.date AS date,
        IFNULL(metric_level, LAST_VALUE(metric_level IGNORE NULLS) OVER(window_latest)) AS metric_one

        FROM date_arr d
        LEFT JOIN metric_one_raw i
        ON d.date = i.date
        WINDOW window_latest AS (ORDER BY d.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

    ),

    metric_two_raw AS (

        SELECT 
        date,
        metric_level

        FROM database
        WHERE metric_name = 'metric_two'

    ),

    metric_two_gapless AS (

        SELECT
        d.date AS date,
        IFNULL(metric_level, LAST_VALUE(metric_level IGNORE NULLS) OVER(window_latest)) AS metric_two

        FROM date_arr d
        LEFT JOIN metric_two_raw i
        ON d.date = i.date
        WINDOW window_latest AS (ORDER BY d.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

    ),

    metric_three_raw AS (

        SELECT 
        date,
        metric_level

        FROM database
        WHERE metric_name = 'metric_three'

    ),

    metric_three_gapless AS (

        SELECT
        d.date AS date,
        IFNULL(metric_level, LAST_VALUE(metric_level IGNORE NULLS) OVER(window_latest)) AS metric_three

        FROM date_arr d
        LEFT JOIN metric_three_raw i
        ON d.date = i.date
        WINDOW window_latest AS (ORDER BY d.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

    )

    SELECT
    *
    FROM metric_one_gapless
    LEFT JOIN metric_two_gapless USING(date)
    LEFT JOIN metric_three_gapless USING(date)
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Generate the dates
- Use a `cross join` to get all the rows
- Use a `left join` to bring in your data
- Use `last_value()` to fill in `NULL` values.

In other database, I would prefer `lag(ignore nulls)`, but BigQuery does not support that.

So:

```
select d, m.metric,
       coalesce(mm.metric_level,
                last_value(mm.metric_level ignore nulls) over (partition by m.metric order by d)
               ) as metric_level
from (select distinct metric from metrics) m cross join
     unnest(gnerate_date_array(date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 year), interval 1 day) d left join
     metrics mm
     on mm.metric = m.metric and mm.date = d;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon. That query doesn't quite get me all the way there though.

It only gives me a table with three columns -  date, metric_name, metric_level and a full year of data for each metric. so (365 x number of metrics) rows long and 3 columns.

I need to get a table that has a column per metric. so 365 rows, and (number of metrics) columns across.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research, I came up with somethig, due you are using left join and there would be more than one, or even, variable number of left joins, and also you can not use `declare` in BigQuery Web UI, you probably need better to use the API Rest BigQuery [feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries), you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) the dependencies, you can use C#, GO, JAVA, NODE.JS, PHP, PYTHON or RUBY coding, this would allow you to assign in to a variable the number of metrics, so I recommend first to do a select distinct to know how many metrics are there and after that you can save them into a variable and after that do a loop to execute the left joins you want.

I hope this information helps you, and I'm here if you need more information.